# Getting wrapped data via Vue-Laravel API Resource connection

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, api, vue.js

I'm using Laravel and Vue connected via API,
Everything works fine. 
I asked to get offer via method from Vue:

```
      getOffer(id) {
              this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offers/'+id)
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(result => this.offer = result)
          }
      },
```

And I recived this:

```
{
"body": "xx"
"title": "yy"
}
```

and then put it into offer variable:

```
    data() {
        return {
            offer: {
                title:'',
                body:''
            }
        }
    },
```

and I used it into template

```
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{offer.title}}</h3>
              <div>
                <br>
                {{offer.body}}</div>
            </div>
```

easy, all works fine

Now I decided to use Laravel Resource. This is wrapping data into "data" object within json response, so I got now this:

```
{
     "data": {
        "body": "xx"
        "title": "yy"
     }
}
```

and my template is blank - can anyone tell me how should I change the code, to work with new data object? And how I could work with it, when It will contain more objects, like:

```
 {
     "data": {
        "body": "xx"
        "title": "yy"
     },
     "data2":{
        "body": "xx"
        "title": "yy"
     },
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

getOffer function should be modified to use `result.data` instead of raw `result`:

```
  getOffer(id) {
          this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offers/'+id)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(result => this.offer = result.data)
      }
  },
```

now it works again